# Matlab number formatting?

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I'm having some difficulties processing some numbers. The results I get are some like:

```
0.000093145+1.6437e-011i
0.00009235+4.5068e-009i
```

I've already try to use `format long` and as alternative passing to string and then `str2num` and with no good results also. Although is not being possible to convert them properly as I want (e.g. to a number with 9 decimals) If nobody is able to help me, at least I would appreciate if someone can tell me how to interpret the meaning of the i base.

Comment: What are the expected results?

Comment: The expected results were real numbers, only with decimal houses and no bases.. Like I said .. like a number rounded to 9 decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about the [imaginary unit i](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/i.html). If you are just using real number, you could neglect the imaginary part (it is very small). Thus, try:

```
real(0.000093145+1.6437e-011i)
```

Comment: Great, thank you tashuhka! I googled for it for a while and didn't find any usefull information and that clarified me totally! :)

Comment: I am glad I helped you. Don't forget to accept the valid answer to help the community.

Answer (score 1):

After taking `real()` you can also control the decimal place formatting by `sprintf`:

```
sprintf('%0.2f', pi)
```

Will result in:

```
'3.14'
```

Place a 9 instead of a 2 for 9 decimal places.